# Facebook Graph API - Como postar para uma página?

Tags: facebook

Boa tarde.
Preciso saber como adaptar o script abaixo para que eu faça o post na página que o usuário logado é administrador.
Por exemplo, se meu usuário for admin de 3 páginas no face, quero postar diretamente pela página e não como se meu usuário tivesse feito o post na página.

Obs: já alterei o '/me/photos' por 'pagina-id/feed' porem aparece como um post meu na página e não como se a própria página tivesse postado.

```
FB.login(function () {
                FB.api('/page-id?fields=access_token', 'GET', function (response) {

                    FB.api('/' + response.id + '/photos', 'POST', { message: mensagem, url: imagem }, function (response) {
                        if (!response || response.error) {
                            console.log(response);
                            alert('Error occured');
                        } else {
                            alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                        }
                        $("#post-face-action").modal('hide');
                    });

                });

            }, { scope: 'publish_actions, publish_pages, manage_pages' });
```

Comment: É necessário ter as permissões: - [publish_actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-publish_actions) - [manage_pages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-manage_pages) O *id* da página e token de acesso são requisitos. Não testado, mas acredito que é importante obter o token de acesso da página para usar no *post*, e não do usuário. [Créditos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627684/facebook-graph-api-posting-to-fan-page-as-an-admin)